# R mlr3 create TaskregrST duplicate rows?

Tags: r, mlr3

I have a dataframe called tab_mlr with coordinates about 19 features in 788 rows.

```
str(tab_mlr)
```

This object have 788 observations of 21 variables (with 2 variables as Latitude and Longitude). I create an sf object like this :

```
data_mlr <- sf::st_as_sf(tab_mlr, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)
```

data_mlr have 788 features, that's ok. But when i create a task with this data_mlr like this :

```
task <- TaskRegrST$new(
  "mlr",
  backend = data_mlr,
  target = "Hauteur"
)
```

task object have 620 944 rows !!! Why not 788 rows ?

Comment: If you can reproduce this with an example task please open an issue in the GH repo.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that you are making 788 rows for every row, and you have 788^2 rows as a result.

Comment: Yes, 788^2 = 620 944, but why have we 788 rows for every rows and not 1row for every rows ?